# Handling white space and formatting in source control

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs

I work on a team that uses TFS for source control. Recently some team members are complaining that others are checking in files that have been heavily modified in the sense that the IDE (Visual Studio) has done some sort of automatic formatting on them. This is particularly burdensome on users who make heavy use of the comparison functionality. I am admittedly unfamiliar with the nuts and bolts of Visual Studio. One member has suggested that we all use the same editor settings so that this doesn't happen.

Is having all team members adopt the same code editor settings the best way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Having everybody use the same settings is a good idea in general. If everybody adheres to the same format, settings, and conventions, then this can help reduce the "learning curve" when switching between code that another person wrote.

That being said, if most of the differences are whitespaces then that may indicate a shortcoming of the diff tool. Fortunately, Visual Studio allows you to swap out the built-in diff tool with something of your choosing. You just have to find one that works best for your needs. KDiff3 is a pretty good one.

Here's an example on how to configure [KDiff3 with Visual Studio](http://blog.ilab8.com/2010/10/11/configure-kdiff3-in-visual-studio/). There's a setting (possibly a command line parameter) in KDiff that you can set and it will ignore whitespace differences.

Comment: I don't understand why changing the diff tool would help?

Comment: @EdwardThomson TFS has nothing to do with the comparison. The diff tool actually does the compare. The built-in diff tool probably isn't ignoring whitespaces, so you get more false positives and every space/tab change shows up as a changed line. Part of the question really is asking "How do we prevent whitespace differences from showing up in our diff?", isn't it? So changing to a diff tool that ignores whitespaces will help with that part. Unless I read the question wrong.

Comment: That *may* be what the original question is asking.  But I think that the bigger consideration is that whitespace standardization is good, regardless of your diff tool settings, because when multiple users are editing files and making only whitespace changes, this will lead to merge conflicts that can't be automerged.  And having huge swaths of conflicting regions that differ only in whitespace is to be avoided.

Comment: @EdwardThomson I agree, that's why (I thought) the first part of my answer covered that, and if not I apologize. It's good to have standards and get everybody on the same page for whitespace, formatting, brackets, conventions, tools, etc. That would cut down on some of the modifications that show up in the diff. But diffmerge _does_ have problems with whitespace changes - every line with an added or missing space shows up as a changed line (and merge issues like you say). So I feel something that can ignore whitespaces is an acceptable solution.